# Set a timer on 10 AM Rxjs/timer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Could you tell me how can I use `rxjs/timer` to run a method on exact time? I would like to have an initial delay as `1 min` and after that, it should run at `10 AM` like so. But I was not able to do that. I have done like below. But it fires every 2 mins after 1 min delay. But I need as mentioned above functionality. Any clue or can you tell me another approach maybe?

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

  timer(60000, 120000).subscribe(val => {//schedule Notification
            myMethod();
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep running your timer every minute (or whatever precision you need) and trigger it once its 10am.
something like:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

firstRunExecuted:boolean = false;

  timer(60000).subscribe(val => {//schedule Notification
     if(!this.firstRunExecuted)
       {
          myMethod();
          this.firstRunExecuted = true;
       }
      else if(checkIfIts10AM())
          myMethod();
      });
```

**OP's feedback**

```
 timer(60000, 60000).subscribe(val => {//schedule Notification
              const hours = moment().format("H");
              if (hours == '10') this.scheduleNotification();
       });
```

Comment: What is this method? `this.firstRunExecuted()`

Comment: oh, sorry, its not a method, its a property flag so you know that you did run it first time and you dont want to run it every minute anymore but you'll be waiting till some time. it should be set to true. // fixed in answer

Comment: Any help for this method `checkIfIts10AM()` using `moment`?

Comment: well, you could use it as it has all sorts of stuff related to datetime but i personally wouldn't use it just to check if its 10am or not. feels like a bit of an overkill.